# Java Runtime Environment

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I tried to run a Java Applet in my new computer, but I need to install the Java runtime environment, the Terminal window says:

```
jan@ideapad-100-15IBY:~/Bureaublad$ java -jar pressin.jar  
Het programma ‘java’ kan gevonden worden in de volgende pakketten:  
  * default-jre  
  * gcj-5-jre-headless  
  * openjdk-8-jre-headless  
  * gcj-4.8-jre-headless  
  * gcj-4.9-jre-headless  
  * openjdk-9-jre-headless  
 Probeer: sudo apt install <geselecteerd pakket>
```

My question is: which of these options should I use, what are the differences?
And what is the meaning of "headless" ?

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install default-jre` and you'll be fine (Unless that program specifically requires Java 1.8+)